# My for loop in VBA is returning #REF instead of an integer

Tags: vba, excel

I need to take variable x from a cell and get the sum of `1*x+2*x...+5*x` in the neighbouring cell.
My attempt:

```
Public Function uzd1(x)
    Dim a, c, b As Integer
    b = 0
    For a = 1 To 5
        c = a * x
        b = b + c
    Next
   uzd1 = b
End Function
```

Then I type "=uzd1(B1)" in the answer cell, but I only get "#REF!" instead of summary I need.

Comment: what is your neighbor cell in case of Cell "B1" ? is it A1 to A5 ? or C1 to C5 ?

Comment: I'm using B1 cell for X value and B2 cells formula bar for "=uzd(1)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`uzd1` is a cell address and that's why you are getting a #Ref Error.

Change the function name to something else such as `TestCalc`, it will work.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are sending a numeric reference to your function, you need to define `x As Integer (or 'Long' for higher values).

Second, I had issues with **uzd1** (maybe it's a "saved" word in Excel), so I modified it to **uzd**.

Third, since you want to get the sum as a result, define your function to return an `Integer` (or `Long` for higher values).

**Code of modified UDF**

```
Function uzd(x As Integer) As Integer

    Dim a As Integer, b As Integer

    For a = 1 To 5
        b = b + a * x
    Next a
    uzd = b

End Function
```